# Using shadow password from LDAP while using SSSD for identity

Tags: authentication, pam, sssd

I'd like to use SSSD ldap as a provider for shadow entries. It seems to be supported, given the default config with `sssd` installed adds `sss` to both `passwd` and `shadow` in `nsswitch.conf`, but I can't get the shadow entries.

Testing `getent passwd myuser` gives me the right result. `getent shadow myuser` returns nothing immediately (seems to not check with sssd at all).

The shadow entry does exist in LDAP and sssd seems aware of it, since I see this in the logs:

```
[sdap_attrs_add_ldap_attr] (0x2000): [RID#4] Adding pwdAttribute [....] to attributes of [myuser@domain].
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be ever used.

To prevent trying authentication through LDAP bind, I'm using:

```
id_provider=ldap
auth_provider=none
```

Unfortunately only results in:

```
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [dp_pam_handler_send] (0x0100): Got request with the following data
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): command: SSS_PAM_AUTHENTICATE
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): domain: domain
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): user: myuser@domain
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): service: sudo-i
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): tty: /dev/pts/3
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): ruser: myuser
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): rhost: 
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): authtok type: 1 (Password)
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): newauthtok type: 0 (No authentication token available)
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): priv: 1
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): cli_pid: 2368059
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): logon name: not set
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [pam_print_data] (0x0100): flags: 0
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#5] DP Request [PAM Authenticate #5]: REQ_TRACE: New request. [sssd.pam CID #1] Flags [0000].
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#5] Number of active DP request: 1
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [dp_find_method] (0x0100): [RID#5] Target [auth] is not initialized
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [_dp_req_recv] (0x0400): DP Request [PAM Authenticate #5]: Receiving request data.
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): DP Request [PAM Authenticate #5]: Request removed.
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): Number of active DP request: 0
(2023-08-11  7:04:03): [be[okta]] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0200): sssd.dataprovider.pamHandler: Error [1432158215]: DP target is not configured
```

What configuration am I missing to expose the user attributes as a standard `shadow` database?